# Pass optional SQL to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to inject some optional SQL to prepared statement with the parameter `$and`:

```
public function loadInfoAndStatus($property_id, $property_item_type_id, $and, $returnArray = false)
{
    if (!isset($property_id) || empty($property_id)
     || !isset($property_item_type_id) || empty($property_item_type_id)
     || !isset($and) || empty($and)) {
        error_log(get_class() . " - " . __FUNCTION__ ." : required params not set or empty");
        return false;
    }

    $sql = "   SELECT pi.status, pi.info, pi.property_item_id "
           . " FROM ". self::TABLE ." pi "
           . " JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = pi.country_id "
           . " WHERE pi.property_id = ? "
           . "     AND property_item_type_id = ? "
           .       $this->con->real_escape_string($and)     // <--- here
           . " ORDER BY pi.status "
           . " DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $err = "";
    if (!$stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql)) {
        $err .= "Prepare failed: (" . $this->con->errno . ") " . $this->con->error;
    }

    ...
```

But if I call the function e.g.

```
$row2 = Main::getModel("Property/Item")->loadInfoAndStatus(
    $id
    , $property_item_type_id
    , " AND c.iso = 'DE' "
    , true
);
```

**Hint:** $and can be one of:

```
" AND c.iso <> 'DE' AND c.european <> 1 "
" AND c.iso <> 'DE' AND c.european = 1 "
" AND c.iso = 'DE' "
```

Then I get "Prepare failed" but there is no error message.

**Resulting SQL:**

```
SELECT pi.status, pi.info, pi.property_item_id  FROM property_item pi  JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = pi.country_id  WHERE pi.property_id = ?      AND property_item_type_id = ?  AND c.iso = \'DE\'  ORDER BY pi.status  DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

It works if I don't use `real_escape_string`

Do I have to create new functions for each new sql, or is there another way?

Comment: You don't want to use `real_escape_string` since you are injecting some SQL code.

Comment: But how do I make sure that it is safe then?

Comment: why not add iso in the prepared statement, use question mark placeholder too

Comment: **real_escape_string Doesn't. Make. Anything. Safe** either

Comment: @Kevin, because the SQL can change, it is not always the same

Comment: is this pdo wrapped? maybe just make your query dynamic and just use an array as your payload in execute, much convenient

Comment: you can just add more dynamic and clauses all you want, `AND c.iso <> ? AND c.european <> ?` or much more depending on what you need, then add `DE` and `1` in `->execute()` in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You have to list all possible variants in your function.

This is a toilsome task but you have to realize **that's the only way.**

```
public function loadInfoAndStatus($property_id, $property_item_type_id, $iso = null, $european = null, $returnArray = false)
{
    if (empty($property_id) || empty($property_item_type_id)) {
        error_log(get_class() . " - " . __FUNCTION__ ." : required params not set or empty");
        return false;
    }
    $parameters = [$property_id, $property_item_type_id];
    $sql = "   SELECT pi.status, pi.info, pi.property_item_id "
           . " FROM ". self::TABLE ." pi "
           . " JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = pi.country_id "
           . " WHERE pi.property_id = ? "
           . "     AND property_item_type_id = ? ";

    if ($iso) {
        $sql .= " AND c.iso <> ? ";
        $parameters[] = $iso;
    }
    if ($european === true) {
        $sql .= " AND c.european == 1 ";
    } elseif ($european === false) {
        $sql .= " AND c.european <> 1 ";
    }

    $sql .= " ORDER BY pi.status ";
    $sql .= " DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($parameters)), ...$parameters);
    $stmt->execute();
```

I also removed some cargo  cult code from your method, in case you are interested why

- [Do you really need to check for both isset() and empty() at the same time?](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/empty)
- [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles)

Comment: There is a problem in `bind_param` though. You binded everything as string `s` but property_id and property_item_type_id are integer.

Comment: Can you explain why there are 3 dots at `...$parameters` ?

Comment: Good questions. 1 is not a problem at all. 2 simply because it won't work otherwise. See the explanation here https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple#solutions

Comment: Wow sorry, a typo. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using a whitelist method:

```
public function loadInfoAndStatus($property_id, $property_item_type_id, $and = "", $returnArray = false)
{
    if (empty($property_id) || empty($property_item_type_id) || empty($and)) {
        error_log(get_class() . " - " . __FUNCTION__ ." : required params not set or empty");
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->isSqlInWhitelist($and, array(
        "AND c.iso = 'DE'"
        ,"AND c.iso <> 'DE' AND c.european = 1"
        ,"AND c.iso <> 'DE' AND c.european <> 1"
    ))) {
        error_log(get_class() . " - " . __FUNCTION__ ." : sql is not in whitelist.");
        return false;
    }

    $sql = "   SELECT pi.status, pi.info, pi.property_item_id "
           . " FROM ". self::TABLE ." pi "
           . " JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = pi.country_id "
           . " WHERE pi.property_id = ? "
           . "     AND property_item_type_id = ? "
           .       $and
           . " ORDER BY pi.status "
           . " DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    ...
```

...

```
protected function isSqlInWhitelist($sql, $whitelist)
{
    if (!empty($sql)) {
        if (!in_array(trim($sql), $whitelist)) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a good one but. 1. there is a builtin  `in_array()` function, no need for such a clumsy homemade solution. 2. that bizarre `!$stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql)` is *still* in place. you should really get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks, I will improve the answer :)

Comment: you can make this function in one line, `return !empty($sql) && in_array(trim($sql), $whitelist);`

Comment: Nah, this returns false if $sql is empty, while it should return true. Because $and is optional.

Comment: Ah yes I just confused the operators. It should be `return !$sql || in_array($sql,$allowed)`; means "return true if $sql is not empty or in_array returns true"